# Using 'UpdatePanel' still takes my page to the top where there is a slideshow

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, slideshow, scriptmanager

I have a slideshow at the top of the page and a form at the bottom. But as soon as the image in the slideshow changes,it takes me to the top of the page. So i can't fill a form or do anything at the bottom. Looks like it keeps posting the page again, however i have taken all necessary actions to avoid that.

Here are my controls:

```
      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="3000"    OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
                </asp:Timer>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" Height="388px" Width="936px" runat="server" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and here is the code-behind:

```
 protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetImageUrl();
}
private void SetImageUrl()
{
    Random _rand = new Random();
    int i = _rand.Next(1, 5);
    Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Slideshow/" + i.ToString() + ".jpg";
}
```

Comment: Does setting `<%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>` help?

Comment: it does help a little while i am scrolling.but still keeps posting back with the slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="3000"    OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
                </asp:Timer>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" Height="388px" Width="936px" runat="server" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" />
        </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Attribute 'EventName' is not a valid attribute of element 'PostBackTrigger'. How do i solve this error?